# MPMoviePlayerController overlapped by presenting modal viewcontroller

Tags: ios, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller, autolayout, modalviewcontroller

I added a MPMoviePlayerController's view to my view of a viewcontroller, that i present on an iPad with UIModalPresentationFormSheet. This works fine so far, but when i tap the fullscreen button, the movie view changes to fullscreen but after the animation the modal viewcontroller appears above the view.

The only code I use is the following:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
        [self.player prepareToPlay];
        self.player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
        self.player.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self.view addSubview:self.player.view];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterFullScreen) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:self.player];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didEnterFullScreen) name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification object:self.player];
    }
- (void) updateViewConstraints
{
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    if (!self.addedContraints) {
        [self.player.view autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        self.addedContraints = YES;
    }
}
```

[image: Error]

This happens when I try to hide the viewcontrollers view.
[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I got your problem correctly. But I suspect that you run into the issue of MPMoviePlayerController not actually using the view you have integrated into your view-hierachy  once it is set into fullscreen mode. In other words, pressing the fullscreen button does enforce MPMoviePlayerController to use a new/different view than the one you have added into your stack - it does in fact display directly on the key window once in fullscreen. If you want to prevent that behaviour, you will have to implement your own means of "fullscreen" and add a custom control that allows for that.

Comment: ..or you could just as well simply hide your custom view as soon as the player will enter fullscreen.

Comment: I think this is not the problem. I have a simple UIViewController which has the MPMoviePlayerController's view as a normal subview. This works fine in the "embedded" case. But with the MoviePlayer's controls i can switch to fullscreen. If I do this, it correctly animates the embedded view to fullscreen but after animation, the modal viewcontroller appears on top as seen in the screenshot.

Comment: So why not hide that view on MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreen ?

Comment: It only hides the viewcontrollers view and it looks the the above screenshot but wich a grey background in the middle instead of that black one. T

Comment: Well then hide the entire modal view.

Comment: But this is the superview of the MPMoviePlayerController. And using a MPMoviePlayerViewController directly causes the same result

Comment: It is not the superview of MPMoviePlayerController's view when using  fullscreen mode, that is what I tried to tell you several times.